# Cross-browser CSS horizontal nav with dropdowns - is there such a thing?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I've created a website with horizontal navigation and one level of dropdown menu on each. It works great in all browsers except IE7 (dropdowns don't work) and IE6 (each `<li>` and `<a>` is 100% body width). I'm loathed to go through another 10 tutorials on the web and test each one in all browsers. Debugging my current one will probably take even longer.

I wondered if anyone has a concrete solution that works in all browsers? It's such a common design element. I'm happy to rely on CSS, Javascript, browser hacks, etc - whatever produces a consistent usable nav in all browsers.

**tl;dr** What code do you use for horizontal nav with drop-down menus, to work in IE6 and IE7?

Comment: I wish I could -.- It still accounts for 7% of traffic to the site I'm replacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Suckerfish Dropdowns"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/) is what springs into my mind.

Here's an updated version: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Note that the required JavaScript code to make it work in IE6 is included.

Answer (score 1):

Almost in all of my designs, I had to add [conditional styles](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for the stinky browsers IE6, IE7 and IE8. And to share with you, IE9 is not better, as it doesn't support CSS3 Transitions. Anyway, I strongly suggest that you stop searching an all-encompassing solution and try to create conditional styles and if necessary, even [conditional scripts](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml) for IE, due to these reasons:

1. We developers almost always need to support IE as it has a considerable [browser market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/).
2. IE has many [known problems](http://www.queness.com/post/683/10-awful-ie-bugs-and-fixes) which are never solved by Microsoft, and community found tricks and workarounds for it.
3. Addressing IE separately is known to cost less, than trying to address IE and other browsers in a package (experience)